# Can you recursively extend templates in Play Framework?

Tags: templates, playframework

In [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org/), Can one use the `#{extends}` tag recursively?

I.e., in a child template, extend a parent template, and in the parent template, extend yet another template, like so:

*child.html:*

```
#{extends 'parent.html' /}
<h1>I'm a child</h1>
```

*parent.html:*

```
#{extends 'grandparent.html' /}
<h1>I'm a parent</h1>
<div id="content">#{doLayout /}</div>
```

*grandparent.html:*

```
<h1>I'm a grandparent</h1>
<div id="more-content">#{doLayout /}</div>
```

(Documentation on the `extends` tag:
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/templates#inheritance )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. No problem's at all. It's even a good rpactice to reuse code in different sections of your application.